# How can the administrator get the "Shared Calendar" added by the user?

Tags: powershell, api, exchange-server

I'm Administrator.
How can the administrator get the "Shared Calendar" added by the user with OWA Calendar?

https://office365itpros.com/2020/02/27/adding-your-personal-calendar-owa/

Comment: hi and welcome to SO, please do some research (at least with google) before asking for help, it's possible of course in many ways, Exchange Web Services/Office 365 API/Exchange Server Powershell etc..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "getting" the calendar? You want to see how many users have made use of the feature?

Comment: I would like to find out who used this feature and added a personal account. The reason is that users who used this function before disabling this function can continue using it. It's a problem for security.